# Windows Search programmatically using C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a WPF application, I am trying to get files consuming large storage in the system.I want to achieve programmatically the below:

open windows search ,
Type size:gigantic ,
get the files listed into the application

[image]

I tried the below code:

```
public void GetFiles( )
        {
            string connectionString = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=\"Application=Windows\"";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            string query = @"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
               @"WHERE scope ='file:" + @"C:\" + "' and FREETEXT('size:gigantic')";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();

            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What are you looking for ?Does this code give an error ? What happened when you ran this code ? Please clarify .;)

Comment: Id guess you arent getting results because its trying to search for text "size:gigantic" rather than looking against size for bigger than...

Comment: @TusharGupta: I get zero results found

Comment: @BugFinder: Could U please gimme a solution which could do that ?

Comment: @Apoorv you've been on this site nearly 2 years, we dont code for you - google has plenty of examples

Comment: I think your expectations are probably wrong, its windows explorer that turns that size:gigantic to a real statement. Your code needs to do that for you

Comment: Have you tried instead of `FREETEXT('size:gigantic')` something like `FREETEXT('size:> 5000000')`?

Comment: @BugFinder I understand how stackoverflow works.It was my colleague who posted this question and was following all this :)

Comment: I think sharing accounts would be considered bad form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `gigantic` definition you are using.You must define what you consider `gigantic` in your application. The following code works, so just change the size for what you consider `gigantic`:

```
public void GetFiles( )
    {
        string connectionString = "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties=\"Application=Windows\"";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);string query = @"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
           @"WHERE scope ='file:" + @"C:\" + "' and size>5000000";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();

        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: How can i filter files of type PDF and how can i filter multiple file types like mp4,mkv,wmv. with single query ? can you please provide me the query ?

Comment: You can use `LIKE`, for example something like `string query = @"SELECT System.ItemName FROM SystemIndex " +
               @"WHERE scope ='file:" + @"C:\" + "' and size>5000 and System.ItemName like ANY ARRAY['%.jpg','%.wmv']";` This would return all `jpg` and `wmv` files. Anyway, you can check all this [here(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231256(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: this query returns me zero results, please provide a working query

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use this lib [Win API CodePack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows7APICodePack/). There is Shell namespace in  it which  contains all useful  methods for using shell search the same as  Windows Explorer is using. In case you are using WinRT subsystem  for Win8.1 or upper you may look into Windows.Storage.Search namespace to find useful methods for you.

In case you will use CodePack need to inform you that you can execute search queries only on STA thread(since it's COM) so plan your architecture accordingly

Comment: I am looking for windows 8 and above and a non - WinRT API as i am using it for WPF application, Please help !

Comment: Than WinApi CodePack is your choice. Look into ShellSearch and ShellSearchCondition classes.